# Does the Ubuntu Touch web-brower app need some extra css styling, to style buttons and such

Tags: ubuntu-touch, css

The `Show alert box`, renders differently than in Firefox, IE and Chrome.

Does it need an extra styling options to style it? Like `-webkit`, `-moz`. Or can I keep using the w3c standard like `border`, `border-radius` and such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to style the form elements on a web page using CSS, not the alert box itself, right?

By default form controls in the touch browser have the default QtWebKit look’n’feel, not the Ubuntu SDK’s one.

Form controls can be fully styled using CSS (there are some limitations, [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms) is a good read on the topic).

The standard CSS properties should work, for example [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: What i get from this answer is if I style a `input` tag with  `border`, `border-radius` and `background-color` then it will render them as such. i dont have to use a vendor type style to style it:`-ubuntu-web-app-border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;`?

Comment: @blade19899 No you don't have to, the Touch browser uses qtwebkit so the rendering engine is Webkit.